# Sequence numbers in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, numbers, sql-server-2012, sequence

For example you have a table where you define its definition of one of its column to use a sequence number like follows

```
CREATE TABLE Sales.MyOrders
(
orderid INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_MyOrders_orderid PRIMARY KEY
CONSTRAINT DFT_MyOrders_orderid
DEFAULT(NEXT VALUE FOR Sales.SeqOrderIDs),
.....
```

If you manually insert some values into this table where you explicitly say orderid  = 1;

would the sequence number update as well?

Just I think if it doesn't there are higher chances for primary key violations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, the  sequence number is not update as well.** And [you can check it easily](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58553/1/0) following this 3 simple steps:

1) Create the sequencer and the table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE S as int;

CREATE TABLE MyOrders
(
n int,
orderid INT NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT DFT_MyOrders_orderid
DEFAULT(NEXT VALUE FOR S)
);
```

2) Insert some values:

```
insert into myorders ( n) values (1);
insert into myorders ( n) values (2);
insert into myorders ( n, orderid) values (3,3);
insert into myorders ( n) values (4);
```

3) Check results:

```
| N |     ORDERID |
----|-------------|--
| 1 | -2147483648 |
| 2 | -2147483647 |
| 3 |           3 |   <-- by hand entry
| 4 | -2147483646 |   <-- no gap
```

**Conclusion**

`DEFAULT` clause is only executed when no value (null) is assigned to column. If you provide a value to column then sequencer is not called.

Comment: I guess therefore Im not convinced sequence numbers are better than identity as there are more complications in trying to insert a value into a table that has a column with identity...Therefore you will have less issues with primary key violations

Comment: Of course, to populate a PK is better an identity column. Sequences are intended for more flexible purposes as share a sequence between objects, to have more then one autonumeric field per  table, ...